# Fetch of Core-Data is resulting in duplicate items

Tags: swift, core-data

In my `iOS` `Xcode8` project using `Swift`, I'm performing a `fetch` of my `Core-Data`:

```
func searchFoods() {

    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Foods")

    print("Searching Database for \(searchVariable)...")

    var subPredicates : [NSPredicate] = []

    let codeSearch = NSPredicate(format: "codeText contains[c] %@", "\(searchVariable)")
    subPredicates.append(codeSearch)        

    request.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: subPredicates)
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(request)
        if results.count > 0 {
            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
                if let item = result.value(forKey: "title") as? String {
                    // Maybe put a loop of some kind to only append the found item count??
                    searchArray.append(item)
                    myTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Fetch failed...")
    }

}
```

However my `searchArray` that is a `[String]` of the search results created many duplicates I know are not there; it's listing them 2 or 3 times.  Can't figure out how to limit the appending to just the result count amount.  If I search fruit, it might return an `array` like `bananas, strawberries, peaches, oranges, bananas, strawberries, peaches, oranges` etc, repeating. Can someone please help?

Comment: The obvious question at this point is, how do you know they're not really there?

Comment: Because I'm testing this app, and I remove all prior data and load new data each time I run the app, into CoreData.  Again I'm testing at this point.  Going live it won't be this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing in the code that would cause duplicates in the fetch results. If they're not actually present in the persistent store, the likely cause is that you're doing this:

```
                searchArray.append(item)
```

But there's no sign of ever clearing out past results. Your sample results are consistent with this-- if there are four results, you add them to the array once, then later add them again.

It's also possible that there's a problem with your table view data source methods, but you're probably driving that directly from the contents of `searchArray`.

Comment: I looked in another area of my code and you were right, that I was not clearing prior past results.  Thank you.